# Values error to unpack in python file (expected 3)

Tags: python

I am new to Python.
I want to write a example using I/O file but I have a problem.

Input.txt is:

```
10 , 4 , #
```

This is my code:

```
f = open("Input.txt", "r")
text = f.read()
m, n, c = text.split("\n")
m = int(m)
n = int(n)
f. close()

out_text = (c * m + "\n") * n
f = open("Output.txt", "w")
f.write(out_text)
f.close()
```

When I run this code, I have this error:

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

Can anyone help me with that?  What is this error ???!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error throw by below code

```
m, n, c = text.split("\n")
```

Which caused by `split` return less then 3 items, while you expecting 3 (i.e. `m, n, c`)

```
# This should throw the same error
m, n, c = ["one"]
m, n, c = ["one", "two"]

# This should work
m, n, c = ["one", "two", "three"]
```

To fix the issue, review your `split` call, Paandittya's answer should have everything you need

Answer (score 0):

```
text = "10, 12, #" 
# Here split the string using comma and not newline char.
m, n, c = text.split(",")  
print(m, n, c) 
m = int(m) 
n = int(n)
out_text = (c * m + "\n") * n 
print(out_text)
```

You should split the string using comma and not newline char `\n`. In case your text file has multiple lines then better use `lines = file.readlines()` and then

```
 .... 
for line in lines:
    m, n, c = line.split(",")
 ....
```

So finally your code will look something like this

```
with open("Input.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines() 

# Keep in mind that using "w" will 
# overwrite contents of file and not
# append to it
out_file = open("Output.txt", "w")


for line in lines:
    m, n, c = line.split(",") 
    m = int(m) 
    n = int(n)
    out_text = (c * m + "\n") * n 
    out_file.write(out_text) 

out_file.close()
```

**About the error**

*ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)*

Given that you were trying to split the text using separator `\n` suggests that you have multiple lines. Lets understand with an example and say your file had 5 lines like this:

```
1, 2, #
3, 2, #
1, 3, #
8, 2, #
3, 5, #
```

Now when you read this using `f.read()` the resultant string will effectively be like this

```
"1, 2, #\n3, 2, #\n1, 3, #\n8, 2, #\n3, 5, #"
```

And when you split it using `\n` you got a list as shown below

```
['1, 2, #', '3, 2, #', '1, 3, #', '8, 2, #', '3, 5, #' ]
```

AND NOT

```
['1', ' 2', ' #'] and so on
```

Therefore when you instruct python to unpack list with 5 elements into 3 variables `m, n, c` it raises error that 5 values cannot be uniquely assigned (or unpack) to 3 variables.

Hope this answers your query.

Comment: You could get the error message with a single line of input, too; `"10 , 4 , #".split("\n")` simply returns a list containing the whole string, and `"10 , 4 , #\n".split("\n")` returns `["10 , 4 , #", ""]`

Comment: @tripleee In the case you mentioned the error will be `ValueError: not enough values to unpack` while in question it's `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)`.

Comment: @Paandittya     see my input.text is  10 \n 4 \n #  not  10 , 4 , #  and the output that i want  is like this : ########## \n ########## \n ########## \n ##########   so it means that my inputs are spiliting with \n not  ,.

Comment: In your question, you have clearly mentioned that Input.txt DO have `,` in between. I would suggest that you clearly and accurately post the text file else it won't be possible to pinpoint the exact problem.

Comment: Also the output you desire is obtained when you split the string using `,`. I have tested it and already getting the output you mentioned.